# Is there a way to use find and replace for multiple lines at once in R or RStudio?

Tags: r, replace, find

Is there a way to use find and replace for multiple lines at once in R or RStudio?

Here is the data I'm using for this example:

```
# example data

## starting data

### mtcars
head(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
colnames(mtcars)


## ending data

### AirPassengers   
head(AirPassengers)
length(AirPassengers)
is.na(AirPassengers)
```

I know I can just use the find and replace buttons to change `mtcars` to `AirPassengers` by doing so 1 line at a time or by highlighting/copying/pasting, but I want to know if it's possible to change multiple lines at once in R or RStudio.

Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT 1: Restructured question to make answer more clear.

Comment: Did you meant to replace all from the menu i.e. search for 'mtcars' and in replacement 'AirPassengers'

Comment: Kind of. I want to know if I can use find and replace to change different text in multiple lines at once. I need to restructure the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps in **RStudio**:

1. Select **the 3 lines** *head/str/colnames*
2. **ctrl+f**
3. In the find write "**mtcars**" and in replace write "**AirPassengers**"
4. Click on **All**

Comment: This answers the question as I wrote it, but I think that I wrote it incorrectly. Sorry for this. I want to know if I can use find and replace to change different text in multiple lines at once. I need to restructure the question.